# How to set wrapping background color on placeholder text?

Tags: css, html, placeholder

How do I set the placeholder background as seen with the blue below on the image?

[image: Valid XHTML]

**Update**

So alright, the background of the input field can be set by `::-placeholder` but how do we get the background color on the placeholder text to not extend beyond the text?

Comment: As in background-color? What have you tried - this isn't totally clear... For your reference: [Style Placeholder Text](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

Comment: I think this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 1):

For webkit:

```
#id::-webkit-input-placeholder {background:blue;}
```

For Firefox:

```
#id::-webkit-input-placeholder {background:blue;}
```

Comment: This seems to color the background for the whole input field. How would I wrap the background color to not extend beyond the text, as seen on the example image?

Comment: @Numbers I don't know of a way to do that. If you want to select the text as was done in your screenshot, you can use the javascript `select()` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   background-color: blue;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   background-color: blue;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   background-color: blue;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   background-color: blue;  
}
```

You can also style other pseudo elements for the input such as:

```
input#thisInput:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   background-color: red;
   color:black;
}
```

Comment: This seems to color the background for the whole input field. How would I wrap the background color as seen on the example image?

Comment: don't know.  background-size doesn't seem to have any effect on these pseudo elements. neither does setting a width

Answer (score 0):

in css or directly on the code:

`background-color:#XXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`::placeholder` pseudo element](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/), but it's a non-standard element and not supported by all browsers.